# How to merge Linear Layout and Table Layout at android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm new android. I have a little bit stack in designing layout for Android. In my scenario, I have two button with Linear Layout. Here my **xml**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="@color/isp_home_color"
    >

<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sync_text"
        android:background="@color/sync_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/btn_syncpin"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/topup_text"
        android:background="@color/topup_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/btn_topup"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <!--Table Layout will come here -->

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here image for this.

[image]

When I add new TableLayout inside Linear Layout. I got this.

[image]

Here my **xml** for Table Layout.

```
   <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



   </TableLayout>
```

Actually, I don't want like this. I want two button as shown in first image. Then, next table layout will occur under this two button. Please help me how can I do this layout. Please pointing to me how to make this. Thanks with advanced.

Comment: Pack it all into a Relative layout? Because LinearLayout places things one after the other, that is why this behavior. The culprit being `android:orientation="horizontal"` so after you add two buttons, the Table layout comes after these two buttons in a Horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give orientation as vertical to the LinearLayout not the TableLayout.Put Two buttons in a LinearLayout with orizontal orientation and give orientation "vertical" for the parent LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#456789"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
          android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_syncpin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:text="tring/"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_topup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#978969"
        android:text="topup_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ! When I add this, first two button is didn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, I just checked it on my Machine and it works as desired, although the background preference and the display strings have been removed.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_syncpin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_topup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

take Relative Layout as a parent layout.

Following is an example. it will display your buttons and table layout too

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/isp_home_color"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_syncpin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/sync_text_color"
                android:text="@string/sync_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_topup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/topup_text_color"
                android:text="@string/topup_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >
        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer tells only implementation of button_bar_layout for all android versions with buttons at the bottom/top of an activity which look like AlertDialog with OK/Cancel buttons.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:dividerPadding="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="One" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="Two" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Credits: Who else ? [Johnkil](https://gist.github.com/johnkil/2471342)

Comment: Does not answer the Question OP asked originally. He wants two buttons at the top, one table layout below them.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way here i gave you alternative to achieve your requirement from give all of above
1. header.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/isp_home_color">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sync_text"
        android:background="@color/sync_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/btn_syncpin"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/topup_text"
        android:background="@color/topup_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/btn_topup"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
2.main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/header"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```